# Why the value of this string is null but if I check if it is null the result is false?

Tags: java, string, null

I am going crazy debugging a Java application and checking if a String object is null.

So I have the following situation. I obtain a `String` object in this way:

```
String notePrecedenti = progetto.getDesNotVal();
```

Using the Eclipse debugger I see that the value of the **notePrecedenti** is:

```
"notePrecedenti"    null    
    hash    0   
    hash32  0   
    value   (id=309)    
        [0] n   
        [1] u   
        [2] l   
        [3] l
```

But now if I do this check (in the code or in the debugger Expression tab): **notePrecedenti == null** it say that the result is **false** (So it means that the String is not `null`).

How is it possible? What am I missing? Why the value is null but when do the check it say that it is not `null`?

Comment: Is it equal `"null"`? Check `"null".equals(notePrecedenti);`

Comment: the fact that value actually has an ID and an charcter array assigned to it, means that the string `"null"` is assigned as a reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value of your string is `"null"`, not `null`. It has 4 characters.

Answer (score 1):

From the debugger it seems that the string is the **string** `"null"`, as opposed to being a java `null` - i.e., it's a four letter string - `'n'`, followed by `'u'`, followed by `'l'`, followed by another `'l'`.

Answer (score 0):

You're comparing "null" string instead of null.